# How to hide textboxes based on a number value?

Tags: c#

I have a form that has users select the number of guests. I would like to hide the extra text boxes that are not needed in the second form.

Example user selects 8 guests on form1 on form2 I would like to hide textbox9 and textbox10 so they are only presented with textboxes 1-8 that they need to fill in the guest names.

What would be the best way to accomplish this using Windows Forms C# in Visual Studio?

Here is an example but it seems very repetitive

```
private void DisplayTextBoxs()
    {
        if (xBillInformationForm.dGuestNumber == 1)
        {
            xCustomer1Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer1TextBox.Visible = true;
        }
        if (xBillInformationForm.dGuestNumber == 2)
        {
            xCustomer1Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer1TextBox.Visible = true;
            xCustomer2Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer2TextBox.Visible = true;
        }
        if (xBillInformationForm.dGuestNumber == 3)
        {
            xCustomer1Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer1TextBox.Visible = true;
            xCustomer2Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer2TextBox.Visible = true;
            xCustomer3Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer3TextBox.Visible = true;
        }
        if (xBillInformationForm.dGuestNumber == 4)
        {
            xCustomer1Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer1TextBox.Visible = true;
            xCustomer2Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer2TextBox.Visible = true;
            xCustomer3Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer3TextBox.Visible = true;
            xCustomer4Label.Visible = true;
            xCustomer4TextBox.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just only draw the textboxes that are needed in jquery? for(int i = 0; i < userChoice; i++){
Draw a textbox with id = "TextBox' + i;
}

Comment: I probably should have clarified. This is being written in C# using visual studio.

Comment: Post code please...

Comment: have to do it in c# I know I can set the textbox like textbox10.visible = false; just not sure about the logic part of it.

Comment: want to create textboxes dynamically based on user selected number?

Comment: how about holding references of your textboxes in a List<TextBox> and then use a for-loop to hide or show the needed textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

For a limited maximum number of guests, you could do

```
Textbox2.Visible = userChoice >= 2;
Textbox3.Visible = userChoice >= 3;
```

etc.

For a large number of guests/textboxes, this becomes unwieldy.

Comment: This might be the easiest as it is only 10 text boxes

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically build up your form you could put all you textboxes in a array and loop through them. But we can't give a good answer unless you post your code

```
TextBow[10]textboxes;
textBoxes[0] = your first textbox
textBoxes[1] = you second textbox

For(int i = userChoice -1; i < textBoxes.Length; i++){
   textBoxes[i].Visible = false;
}
```

So my code starts from the userChoice and goes through all the textboxes in the array

Comment: Sorry I didn't have any specific code for this yet as I was still trying to wrap my head around it. I've posed some code but it seems like it is very repetitive

Comment: My answers makes sure you don't need any repetition

Answer (score 0):

Try looping

```
var quantity = convert.ToInt32(xBillInformationForm.dGuestNumber);

<table>
    for(int i=1, i<=quantity; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label id="name">Name</label>
                <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="address" />
            </td>
        </tr>        
    }
</table>
```

And further you can add two buttons or link like "add guest" and "remove guest" in second form and handle it by jquery

Comment: It's a Windows Forms application (desktop) not ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: this is **for loop** only. you can use anywhere. I mean c# coding logic is same for all i.e. MVC, Asp.Net or windows form app. you just need to change your syntax and implement this logic anywhere you want.